# How can i Age adjust the proportions of my covariates in a multiple stratified data set?

Tags: spss, stratification, predictor, adjustment, age

I am doing a cross sectional analysis in a huge data set.

The initial descriptive analysis is stratified by gender, 4 calendar periods and smoking status which gives me the proportions within the groups of my categorical covariates (BMI, Income, Education). This descriptive analysis gives me crude proportions and I need these proportions to be age adjusted...

I do have the cat_age variable of my set and i plan to use the female population distribution to standardize the female age variable and the males with the males ...

Comment: At the moment it is a bit difficult to see what you are trying to do. Could you give us a few more details?

Comment: I am trying to describe by gender former, never and current smokers according to my covariates in the form of comparable proportions based on the above explained stratification .... but this proportions need to be age adjusted not crude ones (which i have)... I am working with spss